# Load site on host machine through vagrant results with connection timeout error

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualbox

Ive installed nginx (from source) on my virtualbox machine.
Im trying to load the default page of nginx on my host machine and receive an error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
The weird thing is that it works pretty well inside my guest machine..
it respond to:
curl -i http://localhost:80 as expected on my guest machine with nginx default page.

I guess I have some network configuration issues and I couldnt find a way to fix it.
I tried to use any combination of portfowarding with ip configuration in my vagrantfile. Also tried to change the listening port on /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf file but it didnt work.

Here is my current vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-puppet"
  config.ssh.username = 'root'
  config.ssh.password = 'aaa'

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "4"]   
  end  

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.55.50"

end
```

My hosts file:

```
::1         localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.55.50   sites.local
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
server {

    listen      80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/main.access.log;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
```

i tried to found a solution for about 4 hours now and it really get me confused.
Is there anyone with a clue why this is happend?

Environment metadata:

Os: Win 10 Pro

VirtualBox version: 5.0.12

Vagrant version: 1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

In your Nginx server block, you have `server_name localhost`. This explains why you can successfully curl the default page from the guest. If you want to load the site from the host, you should add what you have in your hosts file entry...

```
server_name localhost sites.local;
```

Make sure you restart Nginx and this should work for you if you go to `http://sites.local/`.

Comment: It didnt work, it looks like it take long time to render the page like it has infinite loop or something. i dont know I heard also some people say that i should config nginx to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 because it tries to interpret the url infinetely, but i didnt understand what they ment...

Comment: Hmm. Are you binding to `127.0.0.1` somewhere in your Nginx configuration? Try changing `listen 80` to `listen 0.0.0.0:80` in your server block, restart Nginx, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Still connection timeout :( after i restarted nginx (nginx -s stop, than nginx) it works only from inside the guest machine i dont understand why, maybe firewall configurations? how do i check logs?

Comment: Try commenting out your `forwarded_port` line in the Vagrantfile.

Comment: You'll need to `vagrant reload` for the port change to take effect.

Comment: unfurtunatly it didnt work still connection timeout, maybe the fact that im connecting through wifi influence somehow? I also created access log file and i dont see new lines appear, only when im trying to access within the guest machine.